# How do I combine aes() and aes_string() options

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a plot like this

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt)) + ylab("") +
   geom_line(aes(y=mpg, color="one")) + 
   geom_line(aes(y=qsec, color="two")) + 
   scale_color_manual(name="Val", values=c(one="#105B63",two="#BD4932"))
```

[image]

where I am plotting two lines and specifying a color group for each. Now let's say I want to specify the variables names dynamically as character values which means I'll need to use `aes_string().` If I try

```
v1<-"mpg"
v2<-"qsec"
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt)) + ylab("") +
   geom_line(aes_string(y=v1, color="one")) + 
   geom_line(aes_string(y=v2, color="two")) + 
   scale_color_manual(name="Val", values=c(one="#105B63",two="#BD4932"))
```

I get the error

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'one' not found
```

because now `aes_string()` is trying to parse the color value when I just want a literal character value. And if I try

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt)) + ylab("") +
   geom_line(aes_string(y=v1), aes(color="one")) + 
   geom_line(aes_string(y=v2), aes(color="two")) + 
   scale_color_manual(name="Val", values=c(one="#105B63",two="#BD4932"))
```

I get

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

presumably because the layer doesn't know how to handle two aesthetic directives.

How can I combine `aes()` and `aes_string()` aesthetics or how can I specify literal character values for `aes_string()`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Update: ggplot >=v3.0 supports tidy evaluation and the `.data` pronoun. The recommended way to use both character values and literal values would be

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt)) + ylab("") +
   geom_line(aes(y=.data[[v1]], color=one)) + 
   geom_line(aes(y=.data[[v2]], color=two)) + 
   scale_color_manual(name="Val", values=c(one="#105B63",two="#BD4932"))
```

---

If you want to specify a character literal value in `aes_string()`, the easiest thing would be to use `shQuote()` to quote the value. For example

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt)) + ylab("") +
   geom_line(aes_string(y=v1, color=shQuote("one"))) + 
   geom_line(aes_string(y=v2, color=shQuote("two"))) + 
   scale_color_manual(name="Val", values=c(one="#105B63",two="#BD4932"))
```

This works because `aes_string()` actually runs `parse(text=)` on each of the parameter values. The `shQuote()` function adds quotes around your character value so that when you parse the value, you get a character value back rather than a symbol/name. Compare these two calls

```
class(parse(text="a")[[1]])
# [1] "name"
class(parse(text=shQuote("a"))[[1]])
# [1] "character"
```

Alternatively, you might think of merging `aes()` directives. The `aes()` functions really just return a list with a class of `uneval`. We could define a function to combine/merge these list. For example we can define addition

```
`+.uneval` <- function(a,b) {
    `class<-`(modifyList(a,b), "uneval")
}
```

Now we can do

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt)) + ylab("") +
   geom_line(aes_string(y=v1) + aes(color="one")) + 
   geom_line(aes_string(y=v2) + aes(color="two")) + 
   scale_color_manual(name="Val", values=c(one="#105B63",two="#BD4932"))
```

Comment: Nice, you solved a problem I didn't even realize I had ;) (+1.5)

Answer (score 12):

With *`ggplot2 V3.0.0`* it became really simple :

```
v1<-"mpg"
v2<-"qsec"
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt)) + ylab("") +
  geom_line(aes(y=!!sym(v1), color="one")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=!!sym(v2), color="two")) + 
  scale_color_manual(name="Val", values=c(one="#105B63",two="#BD4932"))
```

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to @MrFlick's excellent answer, you can also use `aes_q` and turn your variables' content into `name`s:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt)) + ylab("") +
  geom_line(aes_q(y=as.name(v1), color="one")) + 
  geom_line(aes_q(y=as.name(v2), color="two")) + 
  scale_color_manual(name="Val", values=c(one="#105B63",two="#BD4932"))
```