# Group clause in ggplot loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to put a ggplot in a loop. The loop is to go over multiple columns. I managed this *without* the group clause in the aes command with the help of an udf I found on another thread:
[How do I combine aes() and aes_string() options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777626/how-do-i-combine-aes-and-aes-string-options)

```
# Necessary for use of BOTH aes and aes_string
`+.uneval` <- function(a,b) {
                              `class<-`(modifyList(a,b), "uneval")
                              }

# Create list of column names
columns = as.character(c("quantity_actual", "price_sale", "quantity_corrected"))

# Loop through the columns
for (i in columns)
{
  print(
        ggplot(demand, aes(x = date) + aes_string(y = i)) +
          geom_line() +
          scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
        )
}
```

However, in another plot where I do need the group clause R is failing to recognise the existence of it

```
for (i in columns)
  {
    print(
            ggplot(demand_year_month, aes(x = year_month) + aes_string(y = i), group = 1) +
            geom_line() +
            scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
          )
  }
```

because it is throwing the error:
'geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?'
My guess is modification of the udf is needed. If so, how? or is there a neater solution? Thank you.

Comment: Try putting `group = 1` in the `geom_line()` layer or inside the global `aes()`.

Comment: Just use `aes(x = year_month, group=1)` or also add `+aes(group = 1)` (rather than putting it after the comma). Right now you are not passing that as an aesthetic. Right now the `ggplot` function just ignores that additional parameter.

Comment: Something as simple as that. I can't believe it. Very grateful for your prompt reply @aosmith
May I ask how you had this idea? Experience?

Comment: @ MrFlick Tried both. Both threw the error:
'Error: geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: y'
Seems y axis has to be mentioned. But thank you for your udf solution.